# Issue with primefaces-8.0 ,omnifaces-1.8 and prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3 combine together

Tags: java, primefaces, omnifaces, prettyfaces

I have an application runing with **primefaces-8.0** and **omnifaces-1.8**.
Everything were working fine before i introduce **prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3**.
The probleme is that the fileupload is not working anymore

```
<p:fileUpload performVirusScan="true" id="file" required="false" class="form-control"  listener="#{demandeManagedbean.upload}"
                                                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/" sizeLimit="3750000"
                                                      fileLimit="1" fileLimitMessage="Vous ne pouvez uploader qu'un seul fichier." update="@none"
                                                      mode="advanced" skinSimple="true"/>
```

The method **upload()** is not call anymore and the converter `converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsIndexConverter"` is not working only `converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"`. But if i remove **fileupload** `converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsIndexConverter"` work.

Find bellow my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.soulsofts</groupId>
    <artifactId>soulsoftsAP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>soulsoftsAP</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>4.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.soulsofts</groupId>
            <artifactId>SendSMSAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ocpsoft/prettyfaces-jsf2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ocpsoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>prettyfaces-jsf2</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
            <id>eclipselink</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library EclipseLink (JPA 2.1)</name>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>maven2-sonaype.net</id>
            <name>oss Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>apache2-https</id>
            <name>Apache 2 https</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>dashboard.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>ecuador-indigo</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/primefaces-ecuador.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.lct.togo.onlinebilling.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ttf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-sfnt</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff2</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-woff2</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>eot</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>eot?#iefix</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#exosemibold</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#exobolditalic</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#exomedium</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#exoregular</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#fontawesomeregular</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping> 
        <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            -1
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Thanks to help me solve this issue or suggest another way to do.

Comment: Suggestion 1: upgrade omnifaces....  2: then create a [mcve] without omnifaces. 3: Remove all other filters. 4: If that still fails, update your question with the info and the [mcve]

Comment: The filter config is incorrect. In the abovelinked duplicate, Ctrl+F on "PrettyFaces".

Comment: Hi all, 
I fixed this issue by adding bellow script to the xhtml page on which i want to uplod document.
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("form[enctype='multipart/form-data']").attr("action", "#{request.contextPath}/demande.xhtml");
            });
        </script>
I do not really understand but it work. If somebody can explain it to it will be good

Comment: It's because the filter config is incorrect. In the abovelinked duplicate, Ctrl+F on "PrettyFaces" for an in-depth explanation and the correct solution.